# Algebraic degree of $\cos\left(\frac{p\pi}{q}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, algebraic-numbers

How can we find the algebraic degree of $\cos\left(\frac{p\pi}{q}\right)$ for $p$, $q$ coprime integers?

I know that the algebraic degree of $e^{\frac{p\pi i}{q}}$ is $\phi(q)$, since cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible. I also know that $$\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}.$$ But my knowledge of abstract algebra is quite slim, and I don't know how to relate these two facts.

I've checked on Google, and I haven't been able to find anything related. Any result or reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**  Assume that $|q|\neq 1$.  There is a quadratic polynomial $f(x)$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{K}:=\mathbb{Q}\Biggl(\cos\left(\frac{p\pi}{q}\right)\Biggr)$ such that $\exp\left(\frac{p\pi\text{i}}{q}\right)$ is a root of $f(x)$.  Prove that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{K}$ by showing that $$\left[\mathbb{Q}\Bigg(\exp\left(\frac{p\pi\text{i}}{q}\right)\Bigg)_{\vphantom{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{1}}}}}^{\vphantom{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{1}}}}}:\mathbb{K}\right]>1\,.$$

Comment: This proves that as long as $q\neq\pm1$, the algebraic degree of $\cos\left(\frac{p\pi i}{q}\right)$ is $2\phi(n)$, right?

Comment: No, it proves that the algebraic degree is $\frac{1}{2}\phi\big(|q|\big)$.

Comment: My bad. Thank you!

Comment: In fact, you have to be a bit careful.  In the case where $q \ne \pm1$ is odd, the answer is indeed $\frac{1}{2}\phi\big(|q|\big)$.  But if $q$ is even, then the algebraic degree of $\exp\left(\frac{p\pi\text{i}}{q}\right)$ is not $\phi\big(|q|\big)$, but $\phi\big(2|q|\big)=2\,\phi\big(|q|\big)$.  Hence, the answer when $q$ is even is $\phi\big(|q|\big)$.