# prove that $x^{20}+(1-x)^{20}-20$ is square free

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, derivatives, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

> Prove that $x^{20}+(1-x)^{20}-20$ is square free (i.e. has no repeated roots).

Note that the claim holds iff $p'(x)$ is coprime to $p(x)$, where $p(x)=x^{20}+(1-x)^{20}-20$. $p'(x)= 20x^{19}-20(1-x)^{19}.$ Also, $\gcd(p,p') = \gcd((1-x)^{19}-20, x^{19}-20)$ and the roots of $x^{19}-20$ are $\sqrt[19]{20} \exp (2\pi i k /19)$ for some $0\leq k\leq 18$ while the roots of $(1-x)^{19}-20$ are $1-\sqrt[19]{20} \exp (2\pi i k/19)$ for some $0\leq k\leq 18$. I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: I just posted my answer. Another elementary way is by straightforward Euclidean algorithm that can be done, for example, [here](https://www.123calculus.com/en/extended-euclide-polynomials-page-1-60-180.html). I have verified that its output in this case is correct.  Still another elementary way is to estimate the difference between $\cos(\frac{2\pi k}{19})$ and $\frac{1}{2}\cdot 20^{-\frac{1}{19}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been reduced to show that $\gcd((1-x)^{19}-20, x^{19}-20)=1$ in $\Bbb C[x]$.

Since both $(1-x)^{19}-20$ and $x^{19}-20$ are in $\Bbb Q[x]$, it is enough to prove $\gcd((1-x)^{19}-20, x^{19}-20)=1$ in $\Bbb Q[x]$.

Let us work in $\Bbb Q[x]$ from now on.

Since $5\mid 20$, $5\not\mid1$ and $5^2\not\mid20$, Eisenstein's criterion tells us $x^{19}-20$ is irreducible. In other words, $x^{19}-20$ is a prime polynomial. Any polynomial that shares a non-constant factor with $x^{19}-20$ must either be a constant multiple of it or have a higher degree. Since $(1-x)^{19}-20$ is neither, it is coprime to $x^{19}-20$.

Comment: I think you want to use Eisenstein with $p=5$, since $2^2$ does divide $20$.

Comment: @RaviFernando Thanks. Of course. LOL.

Answer (score 1):

First, the roots of $x^{19}-20$ are $20^{\frac{1}{19}}\exp(\frac{2\pi ik}{19})$ for $k=0,\cdots,18$,
and the roots of $(1-x)^{19}-20$ are $1-20^{\frac{1}{19}}\exp(\frac{2\pi i \ell}{19})$ for $\ell=0,\cdots,18$.
In order to show that the desired gcd is 1,
we only need to show that there is no common root of the two polynomials.
In other words, there are no $k,\ell\in\mathbb{Z}$
such that
$$
20^{\frac{1}{19}}\exp(\frac{2\pi ik}{19}) = 1-20^{\frac{1}{19}}\exp(\frac{2\pi i\ell}{19}),
$$
or equivalently,
$$
\exp(\frac{2\pi ik}{19})+\exp(\frac{2\pi i\ell}{19})=20^{-\frac{1}{19}}.
$$
Note that $20^{-\frac{1}{19}}$ is a real number,
and for any $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$, if $z_1+z_2\in\mathbb{R}$, then the imaginary parts of $z_1$ and $z_2$ must cancel.
Thus, we only need to consider the case where $\ell=-k$ (since the 19th roots of unity are not symmetric about the y-axis).
Then the above reduces to
$$
\cos(\frac{2\pi k}{19})=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 20^{-\frac{1}{19}}.
$$
Clearly $k\not\in 19\mathbb{Z}$.
Then [the degree of $\cos(\frac{2\pi k}{19})$ is 9](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3441631/806703),
but the degree of $\frac{1}{2}\cdot 20^{-\frac{1}{19}}$ is 19.
This shows that there cannot exist $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that the above holds, as desired.

Comment: Thanks, but could you cite a link to a basic paper introducing the degree of a complex number c (which is the smallest degree of a polynomial with complex coefficients with a root of c)? Or could you provide a more elementary solution?

Comment: @user33096 The concept is discussed in any undergraduate algebra textbook (such as Dummit's & Foote's _Abstract Algebra_) that introduces field theory.

Comment: I think you can also do brute-force Taylor expansions to give upper and lower bounds of the numbers, and argue that the two numbers cannot be equal, though of course this will be a lot dirtier.

Comment: "for any $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$, if $z_1+z_2\in\mathbb{R}$, then $z_1=\overline{z_2}$ " I don't think so. Take $z_1=1+i$ and $z_2=2-i$.

Comment: @mathlove My bad, I meant that the imaginary parts cancel. Fixed.

Comment: "we only need to consider the case where $\ell=-k$" I think that when $\ell=19-k$, the imaginary parts of $z_1$ and $z_2$ cancel.

Comment: @mathlove That's the same as considering $\ell=-k$. I do not restrict $k,\ell$ to be within $[0,18]$. They can be any integers, conveniently.